# Problemas con formulario PHP

Tags: php, html, backend

Tengo un formulario para el logueo de usuarios tal que así:

```html
<div class="login-form">
   <form action="./compruebaLogin.php" method="POST">

        <div class="container">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="user" required>
                <br>
                <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
                <br>
                <br>
            <button type="submit">OK</button>
        </div>
        
    </form> 
</div>
```

Y tengo un archivo llamado `compruebaLogin.php` al cuál redirige este formulario. Sin embargo la redirección funciona mal, ya que me salta la página de error que tengo creada por defecto si la redirección falla. El tema es que este archivo esta en el mismo directorio que el del login en PHP, la ruta que le he puesto es relativa, y el visual studio code hasta me da sugerencias, lo que me hace pensar que el problema no es la ruta.

¿Alguien sabe que ocurre?

Comment: si está en el mismo directorio, no hace falta el  `"./"` deja el action como `compruebaLogin.php`

Comment: no tienes conexión con tu base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente tu problema sea que estás buscando en ora carpeta, ya que normalmente se trabajan todos los archivos de PHP desde una sola carpeta, entonces en tu sintaxis hay algo erróneo:

> `<form action="`./`compruebaLogin.php" method="POST">`

Así es como debería de quedar, retirando el "./" ya que en ese caso estás indicando que debe buscar un directorio arriba, es decir una carpeta anterior.

La otra opción es que hayas escrito mal el nombre, porque veo que escribiste "compruebaLogin" con "L" mayúscula, así que puede que el nombre de tu archivo no tenga esa "L" en mayúscula o que incluso la "c" de "comprueba" en reaidad la hayas escrito como mayúscula, en ese caso deberías escribir "CompruebaLogin.php"

Answer (score 1):

Si estas en el mismo directorio seria

```
           <form action="compruebaLogin.php" method="POST">
           </form>
```

Si tu archivo esta en la raiz y compruebaLogin.php esta en una carpeta seria asi

```
           <form action="carpeta/compruebaLogin.php" method="POST">
           </form>
```

Si tu archivo esta en una carpeta y compruebaLogin.php esta en otra carpeta seria asi

```
           <form action="../carpeta/compruebaLogin.php" method="POST">
           </form>
```

Si tu archivo esta en una carpeta y compruebaLogin.php esta en la raiz seria asi

```
           <form action="../compruebaLogin.php" method="POST">
           </form>
```

Prueba esas formar y me dices como te fue...

Answer (score 0):

Si se encuentran en el mismo directorio trata de reemplazar esto:

```
<form action="./compruebaLogin.php" method="POST">
```

Por esto:

```
<form action="compruebaLogin.php" method="POST">
```